# Where do I run AI logic in MVC app.?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I need to make a swing application for a school project who let 2 AI play against each others on some kind of snake game.

I used a MVC design pattern and created the class I need for some basics test but I'm not sure where I should run the code who makes the AI plays.

The class of `JPanel` I want to run the game into look like that :

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel { 

      public GamePanel (JFrame frame)
      {
      ...
      }

      public paintComponent (Graphics g)
      {
      ... // draw the grid that represent the game
      }
}
```

I tried to put the code who makes the AI plays in the constructor but it wasn't working properly because I need to call the `paintComponent()` method each time an AI play (to refresh the grid who represent the game) and i can't call it because `getGraphics()` gives me a 'null' (I can't call `paintComponent()` without an instance of `Graphics`).

Where am I supposed to place the code who make the AI play? I've never used Swing before so I think I'm missing something obvious, I'm kinda lost...

I hope all of this make sense, English is not my mother tongue and I have some troubles to explain this issue. I really hope someone understand what I meant and can help me!

Comment: The `GamePanel` should have *access* to the model (but the model needs to be a distinct object from any GUI component) which should paint itself according to the state represented in the model.  When the model changes, simply call the `repaint` method of the panel.

Comment: To be a little more explicit, the AI is part of the Model.  When the Model updates, it fires an event (Observer Pattern) that updates any listeners.  For a game though, you typically need a constantly running background thread that "ticks" (executes at regular intervals) so that the AI can be constantly executed.

Comment: More ideas: The Game Loop (that background thread I mentioned) http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html .  And Wikipedia mentions it as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming

Comment: From the perspective of a MVC, the model should define the state, the view should draw that state and the controller should manage the model and view.  So basically, your AI is a model